# Dajaxice form cookie

Tags: python, django, dajaxice

`function create_comment(){`

```
 data = $('.comment_form form').serializeObject();   
 Dajaxice.iwebs.create_comment(Dajax.process,{'content':data.content,'post_id':data.post_id});
 return false;}`
```

In HTML form I use `{% csrf_token %}` cookie. Django wants to use `X-CSRFToken`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax
How can I implement it?

My `ajax.py`

`@dajaxice_register`

`def create_comment(request, content, post_id):

     dajax = Dajax() /n
     dajax.alert('foobar') /n
     return dajax.json()`

Dajaxice works correct but not at forms. The error is "Something goes wrong"

Answer (score 0):

dajaxice works fine for me whenever I set {% csrf_token %}.
Try this instead:

```
data = $('#<form_id>').serializeObject();
Dajaxice.iwebs.create_comment(Dajax.process,{'data':data});
```

please use firebug and see what error u r getting, 403 may mean csrf token issues while if u get 'Dajaxice Exception', it will be likely because of internal errors